# Searching for multiple keywords and location options breaks the job search results alignment on Stack Overflow Careers

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs, design, search

When you search for "full stack engineer" (Keywords) and "San Francisco" (Location) along with two (or more) options such as "offer visa sponsorship" and "offer relocation", it breaks the job search result *alignment*. I would like to share the following screenshots to explain this better.

This is how it looks upon searching for "full stack engineer" (Keywords) and "San Francisco" (Location) ***without*** any other options from "Location" drop-down: ([1st query link](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs?searchTerm=full%20stack%20engineer&location=San%20Francisco&range=20&distanceUnits=Miles))

> [image: screen shot with search for keywords and location only]

This is how it looks upon searching for "full stack engineer" (Keywords) and "San Francisco" (Location) along ***with one*** option i.e. "offer visa sponsorship": ([2nd query link](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs?searchTerm=full%20stack%20engineer&location=San%20Francisco&range=20&distanceUnits=Miles&offersvisasponsorship=true))

> [image: screen shot with search for keywords, location, and a single option]

And finally, this is how it looks upon searching for "full stack engineer" (Keywords) and "San Francisco" (Location) along ***with two*** (or more) options such as "offer visa sponsorship" and "offer relocation": ([3rd query link](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs?searchTerm=full%20stack%20engineer&location=San%20Francisco&range=20&distanceUnits=Miles&offersrelocation=true&offersvisasponsorship=true))

> [image: screen shot with search for keywords, location, and multiple options]

Could this be fixed?

**P.S.**
The *query links* given above will display the updated results as for # of jobs goes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for pointing this out. We're fixing by changing the `height` property to a looser, more appropriate `min-height`. Should be visible shortly.

Answer (score 2):

Here I would like to give the two possible solutions as I am not sure how exactly the original design was suppose to display the search results. There are:

**A)** Display the "search keywords and location options" to the **left of the sort options tabs** ('relevance' | 'most recent')

**B)** Display the "search keywords and location options" on it's **own line** leaving sort options tabs on the next line aligned right.

Please note that there could be possibly more better ways to achieve this result as CSS can do wonders to a design. Although my CSS code fixes the issue but it might have other drawing implications somewhere else. I didn't experiment much. I would leave this to SE's UI/UX team for further experiment.

**A)** To display the number of jobs available along with search keywords and location options to the *left* of the sort tabs ('relevance' | 'most recent') apply the following changes to the current CSS code:

```
#index-hed {
    clear: both;
    height: 42px; /* changed from 35px to 42px */
}

#index-hed h2 {
    border: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    float: left;
    width: 75%; /* added width */
}

#index-hed .tabNav>.-tab>a {
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 20px; /* changed to 20px from 12px */
    padding: 10px;
}
```

will produce the search results as shown in the below screenshots:

Upon searching for "full stack engineer" (Keywords) and "San Francisco" (Location) along with ***one*** option i.e "offer visa sponsorship":

> [image]

Upon searching for "full stack engineer" (Keywords) and "San Francisco" (Location) along with ***two*** (or multiple) options such as "offer visa sponsorship" and "offer relocation":

> [image]

Note: The sort options tabs ('relevance' | 'most recent') got little taller to accommodate the multi-line options i.e. # of jobs available, search keywords and location options but it does produces a *clean* and *tidy* result.

Now lets move on to the second possible solution.

**B)** To display the number of jobs available along with search keywords and location options on it's *own line* apply the following changes to the current CSS code:

```
.list {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    clear: both; /* add this -- No floating elements on either side */
}

#index-hed h2 {
    border: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0px 0px 2px 0px;  /* added 2px bottom-padding so it doesn't touch the sort options tabs below */
    float: left;
}
```

will produce the search results as shown in the below screenshots:

Upon searching for "full stack engineer" (Keywords) and "San Francisco" (Location) along with ***one*** option i.e. "offer visa sponsorship":

> [image]

Upon searching for "full stack engineer" (Keywords) and "San Francisco" (Location) along with ***two*** (or multiple) options such as "offer visa sponsorship" and "offer relocation":

> [image]

Note: Of course, you *lose* some screen real estate when you do the above but does produces a clean result.