# Stack Overflow Careers: 'Create a job alert' message box floats under the sort options tabs

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs, design, search

A few weeks ago I posted the Stack Overflow Careers [job search results overlap issue on the sort tabs](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/263438/searching-for-multiple-keywords-and-location-options-breaks-the-job-search-resul) and it's still a valid issue as long as you are *not* logged in the Stack Overflow Careers site.

Today upon *login* into Stack Overflow Careers website and running a search query for the same keywords and options, I noticed a new addition of '**Create a job alert**' message box (as shown in the screenshots below) which now floats under the sort options tabs as you add the multiple keywords, options to a search query.

Here are the example screenshots along with the corresponding search query link:

1. It looks OK upon searching for "full stack engineer" (Keywords) and "San Francisco" (Location) ***without*** any other options from "Location" drop-down: ([1st query link](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs?searchTerm=full%20stack%20engineer&location=San%20Francisco&range=20&distanceUnits=Miles))

   > [image]
2. This is how it looks upon searching for "full stack engineer" (Keywords) and "San Francisco" (Location) along with one option i.e. "offer visa sponsorship": ([2nd query link](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs?searchTerm=full%20stack%20engineer&location=San%20Francisco&range=20&distanceUnits=Miles&offersvisasponsorship=true))

   > [image]
3. And finally, this is how it looks upon searching for "full stack engineer" (Keywords) and "San Francisco" (Location) along with two (or more) options such as "offer visa sponsorship" and "offer relocation": ([3rd query link](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs?searchTerm=full%20stack%20engineer&location=San%20Francisco&range=20&distanceUnits=Miles&offersrelocation=true&offersvisasponsorship=true))

   > [image]

I liked the concept of 'Creating a Job Alert' based on the given search criteria, but the alert message box styling issue needs a fix.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks for reporting this. The design hardcoded a height on the heading element; apparently we didn't revisit this after adding the new location-based filters. A fix should be going out soon!

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for the hot-fix!